# C functions used in python via ctypes slows down when I add if condition

Tags: python, c, ctypes, compiler-optimization, dot-product

I try to implement a C function that loops over the dataset (randomly generated 1 million feature vectors) and processes dot product operation with a given feature vector at every iteration. It completes the loop very fast (in ~0.05ms).

c code:

```c
void dotProduct(double *parameters, double *feature, double *dataset)
    {
        const int FEATURE_COUNT = parameters[0];
        const int DATASET_COUNT = parameters[1];
        const double THRESHOLD = parameters[2];
        double dotProductResult;

        for (int i = 0; i < DATASET_COUNT; i++)
        {
            dotProductResult = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < FEATURE_COUNT; j++)
            {
                dotProductResult += dataset[i*FEATURE_COUNT+j] * feature[j];
            }

            // if (dotProductResult > THRESHOLD)
            // {
            //     parameters[3] = i;
            // }
        }    
    }
```

python code:

```py
ND_POINTER_PARAMETERS = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, 
                                      ndim=1,
                                      flags="C")
ND_POINTER_FEATURE = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, 
                                      ndim=1,
                                      flags="C")
ND_POINTER_DATASET = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, 
                                      ndim=2,
                                      flags="C")
dotProductLib.dotProduct.argtypes = [ND_POINTER_PARAMETERS, ND_POINTER_FEATURE, ND_POINTER_DATASET]
    
feature = np.random.rand(512,)
dataset = np.random.rand(1000000,512)
parameters = np.array([len(feature), len(dataset), 200, -1], dtype=np.float64)

t = time()
dotProductLib.dotProduct(parameters, feature, dataset)
print("---time taken C: ",1000*(time()-t), "ms")
```

However when I add an `if` condition that checks if the result of the dot product is higher than a given threshold and assigns the index of the vector into the given address, the speed downs dramatically(~500ms) even though it never enters inside the if condition.

Also, the same thing happens when I add `std::cout` instead of variable assignment.

```c
if (dotProductResult > THRESHOLD)
{
    std::cout << dotProductResult << "\n";
}
```

Moreover, if I add an `else` condition and write the same statement in `if` absurdly or if I assign any number, it doesn't speed down.

```c
if (dotProductResult > THRESHOLD)
{
    parameters[3] = i;
}
else
{
    parameters[3] = i;
}
```

or

```c
if (dotProductResult > THRESHOLD)
{
    parameters[3] = 123;
}
```

I use `-O3` flag.
What I am doing wrong? Any suggestion to do such an operation fast?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code is only fast because it doesn't actually do anything! The compiler recognizes that you don't actually use `dotProductResult`, so the function gets [optimized down to literally nothing](https://godbolt.org/z/5Pacsr). When you uncomment your conditional, now the value of `dotProductResult` is used, so it has to actually do the work of figuring out the dot product. If you "add an `else` condition and write the same statement in `if`", then it's fast again because the compiler realizes that's equivalent to this:

```c
void dotProduct(double *parameters, double *feature, double *dataset)
    {
        const int DATASET_COUNT = parameters[1];

        if (DATASET_COUNT > 0)
        {
            parameters[3] = DATASET_COUNT - 1;
        }
    }
```

So it can stop doing the work again.

Comment: Thank you, this enlightened me so much